# Setup Laravel project after cloning

Tags: php, laravel

So I have just cloned big repo with Laravel project, for the moment this folder (lets call it /var/www/project) does not have vendor folder, .env file, autoload files etc.

Is there some kind of detailed united tutorial with all the steps what should I do next? Install composer (it is already installed on my computer, I have other working projects), generate autoload files and vendors?

Which commands should I run in my console (I have Ubuntu 14.04) to make this folder a working virtual host? Or could someone be so kind to give me all the instructions?

Comment: what's your server? apache2 or nginx?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim apache2

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim apache2

Answer (score 45, accepted):

1. run `composer install` to generate depedencies in vendor folder
2. change `.env.example` to `.env`
3. run `php artisan key:generate`
4. configure `.env`

basiclly you need do these things, more info you should check [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2)

Answer (score 10):

**Windows**

Go to the project folder
Shift+Right Click -> Open command window here

**Mac**

Open Terminal, Type "cd " (with a space)
From finder, Drag the project folder
Press Enter to go inside the project folder

**Compose**

```
composer install
```

**Generate Key**

```
php artisan key:generate
```

**Setup Database**

Open the file **.env**
(Assuming wamp or xampp)
Edit values to match your database
Add empty database using phpmyadmin
Include that name in the DB_DATABASE

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=students_data
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

**Get Tables**

```
php artisan migrate
```

**Get default/initial/dummy table values**

```
php artisan db:seed
```

**Run the project**

```
php artisan serve
```

Answer (score 5):

- Install Docker Desktop. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation for details.
- Change working directory to project dir.
- Set up sail dependencies:

  ```sh
  docker run --rm \
      -v $(pwd):/opt \
      -w /opt \
      laravelsail/php80-composer:latest \
      composer install
  ```

  See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#installing-composer-dependencies-for-existing-projects for details.
- Run the docker container:

  ```sh
  vendor/bin/sail up
  ```
- Connect to MySQL container shell:

  ```sh
  vendor/bin/sail exec mysql bash
  ```
- Inside that shell, create the database:

  ```sh
  mysql --password= --execute='create database yourDatabaseName'
  exit
  ```
- Connect to Laravel container shell:

  ```sh
  vendor/bin/sail bash
  ```
- Copy `.env` file:

  ```sh
  cp .env.example .env
  ```
- Generate application key:

  ```sh
  php artisan key:generate
  ```
- Seed the database:

  ```sh
  php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
  ```
- Visit the site on host machine: http://localhost

Answer (score 2):

**1. clone the repo**
`git clone <l_repo>`

**2. go into the repo**
`cd l_repo`

**3. install require packages**
`composer install`

**4. generate the laravel project key**
`php artisan key:generate`

**5. migrate and seed at the same time**
`php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`

**6A.** convert ".env.example" to ".env"

**6B.** change the 'database name' & 'username' & 'password'
`DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=own_databse_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=`

**7. Change the file upload limit for php.ini**
`upload_max_filesize = 4G
     post_max_size = $4G`

**8. Link with storage**
`php artisan storage:link`

**9. start the server**
`php artisan serve`

Answer (score 1):

Follow the Install Laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#installation

Comment: this documentation is not very helpful if I already have folder with files, or maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if there's no vendor folder - you will need to run `composer install` to get all the packages. It will download all the required dependencies to run the project and also will create an `.env` file for local development starter.

To configure virtual host in `apache`, run the following command:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.dev.conf
```

Here `example.dev` is a sample virtual host name. Change it accordingly. Now edit it:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.dev.conf
```

Here's an example contents for this file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ServerName example.dev
    ServerAlias www.example.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you will need to run the following commands to enable virtual host:

```
sudo a2ensite example.dev.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: What should I do if I had `vendor` folder ?

Answer (score 0):

For those people using Laravel Sail or that cloned a project that used Sail from source control, I have made Gist with a simple script and some steps to follow after executing the script. It also explains how to set up the .env file with values that work with the Sail stack. If you do not know what stack the project was using you can find out by looking in the docker-compose.yml file. Also, make sure that you have Docker Desktop installed before running the script, information on this can be found on the Laravel docs. Run the script from the root directory of the project.

https://gist.github.com/LaurenceRawlings/3b4f801cafb2e683f45a3b573dad868d

Answer (score 0):

run composer install
rename .env.example to .env
run php artisan serve

Answer (score -1):

After cloning Laravel app from your repo, run

$ npm install

to install all node package manager depencies. Then run,

$ npm run dev

to test if it'll will run perfectly.
Then run,

$Composer install

to install all composer depencies.
After that,
run
$ Composer dump-autoload

if the autoload file is not included in the vendor folder.

Then run,
$ PHP artisan key:generate

To generate a new App_key for the Laravel application.
Then your app will run successfully.

Very simple and thank me later.